Combine feature extractor with sequence model in Tensorflow
I am following video classification tutorial using transformers from keras tutorials here. I am failing to merge the pretrained feature extractor and the transformer layers into a single model (why I'm doing this - later I want to deploy the model by converting it to onnx format).
The tutorial extract features separately:
def build_feature_extractor():
    feature_extractor = DenseNet121(
        weights="imagenet",
        include_top=False,
        pooling="avg",
        input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3),
    )
    preprocess_input = keras.applications.densenet.preprocess_input

    imgs_shape = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
    inputs = keras.Input(imgs_shape)
    preprocessed = preprocess_input(inputs)

    outputs = feature_extractor(preprocessed)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="feature_extractor"), imgs_shape

After feature extraction on the entire training dataset, they create a transformer model with a classification head:
class PositionalEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, sequence_length, output_dim, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.position_embeddings = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=sequence_length, output_dim=output_dim
        )
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.output_dim = output_dim

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.position_embeddings.build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        # The inputs are of shape: `(batch_size, frames, num_features)`
        inputs = keras.ops.cast(inputs, self.compute_dtype)
        length = keras.ops.shape(inputs)[1]
        positions = keras.ops.arange(start=0, stop=length, step=1)
        embedded_positions = self.position_embeddings(positions)
        return inputs + embedded_positions


class TransformerEncoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, dense_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.dense_dim = dense_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.attention = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim, dropout=0.3
        )
        self.dense_proj = keras.Sequential(
            [
                layers.Dense(dense_dim, activation=keras.activations.gelu),
                layers.Dense(embed_dim),
            ]
        )
        self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization()

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        attention_output = self.attention(inputs, inputs, attention_mask=mask)
        proj_input = self.layernorm_1(inputs + attention_output)
        proj_output = self.dense_proj(proj_input)
        return self.layernorm_2(proj_input + proj_output)


def get_compiled_model(shape):
    sequence_length = MAX_SEQ_LENGTH
    embed_dim = NUM_FEATURES
    dense_dim = 4
    num_heads = 1
    classes = num_classes

    inputs = keras.Input(shape=shape)
    x = PositionalEmbedding(
        sequence_length, embed_dim, name="frame_position_embedding"
    )(inputs)
    x = TransformerEncoder(embed_dim, dense_dim, num_heads, name="transformer_layer")(x)
    x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(classes, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-6)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    # print(model.summary())
    return model

I try to merge everything into one model:
def get_full_model(features_shape):
    feature_extractor = DenseNet121(
        weights="imagenet",
        include_top=False,
        pooling="avg",
        input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3),
    )
    preprocess_input = keras.applications.densenet.preprocess_input

    imgs_shape = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
    inputs = keras.Input(imgs_shape)
    preprocessed = preprocess_input(inputs)
    features = feature_extractor(preprocessed)
    
    sequence_length = MAX_SEQ_LENGTH
    embed_dim = NUM_FEATURES
    dense_dim = 4
    num_heads = 1
    classes = num_classes

    x = PositionalEmbedding(
        sequence_length, embed_dim, name="frame_position_embedding"
    )(features)
    x = TransformerEncoder(embed_dim, dense_dim, num_heads, name="transformer_layer")(x)
    x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(classes, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-6)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    # print(model.summary())
    return model

However, this part fails:
x = PositionalEmbedding(
        sequence_length, embed_dim, name="frame_position_embedding"
    )(features)
    x = TransformerEncoder(embed_dim, dense_dim, num_heads, name="transformer_layer")(x)

The feature extractor generates a (1024,) embedding for each image. However, the Positional Embedding should accept a sequence of 30 such embeddings in the shape of (batch-size, 30, 1024
), but when I'm creating the model, I cannot find a way to pass the sequence information to the PositionalEmbedding layer. Instead, (1024,) is being passed, and then the TransformerEncoder layers crashes:
Arguments received by Softmax.call():
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1024, 1), dtype=float32)
• mask=None

Arguments received by TransformerEncoder.call():
• args=('\<KerasTensor shape=(1024, 1024), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_11760\>',)
• kwargs={'mask': 'None'}



It looks like there is a mismatch between the expected input shapes at different stages of your model. The key issue is that the feature extractor produces a single feature vector for each frame, but the PositionalEmbedding and TransformerEncoder layers expect a sequence of such feature vectors.Extract features: Run each frame through a model to capture visual details.
Stack features: Combine the extracted features from all frames into a single sequence.
Encode and process: Add positional information and feed the sequence to a transformer for analysis.
